# How prove $\sigma(4^p-1)<(2^{p+1}-1)^2$

Tags: number-theory, inequality, prime-numbers, divisor-sum

> If $p$ is an odd prime numbers, show that
>   $$\sigma(4^p-1)<(2^{p+1}-1)^2$$
>   where $\sigma(n)$ stands for the sum of divisors.

I thought of using the formula for $\sigma(n)$:

If $4^p-1=3^k\cdot (p_{1})^{t_{1}}(p_{2})^{t_{2}}\cdots (p_{m})^t_{m}$
we get
$$\sigma(4^p-1)=(4^p-1)\left(\prod_{i=0}^{n}\dfrac{1}{3^i}\right)\left(\prod_{1\le i\le m}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{q_{1}}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{q^{t_{i}}_{i}}\right)\right)$$
but couldn't get any further.

Comment: Since $2^p-1$ and $2^p+1$ are coprime, and $\sigma$ is multiplicative we have
$$
\sigma(4^p-1)=\sigma(2^p-1)\sigma(2^p+1).
$$

Comment: @DietrichBurde,that's  is clear,But  this problem can't only use this reslut

Comment: maybe you can use  Robin's Theorem http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RobinsTheorem.html

Comment: It's easy to show that if $p>3$ then $k=1$. This means $3$ gives a factor $\frac43$ in the abundancy index instead of the less accurate upper bound $\frac32$.